# R - How to calculate the ratio of multiple small time intervals to a large time interval

Tags: r

I have an event interval, `[event_start, event_end]`, and an `even_peak` date in the event interval.

```
event_start <- ymd("2007-01-01")
event_peak <- ymd("2007-10-16")
event_end <- ymd("2008-12-31")
```

I have a data frame of start and end dates/times, like so:

```
id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
start_date <- ymd(c("2007-04-21", "2007-08-23", "2007-12-01", "2008-02-01", "2008-11-15"))
end_date <- ymd(c("2007-09-23", "2007-10-30", "2008-04-01", "2008-07-13", "2009-02-21"))
df = tibble(id = id, start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date, event_peak = event_peak, event_end = event_end)
df
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id start_date end_date   event_peak event_end 
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1     1 2007-04-21 2007-09-23 2007-10-16 2018-12-31
2     1 2007-08-23 2007-10-30 2007-10-16 2018-12-31
3     1 2007-12-01 2018-04-01 2007-10-16 2018-12-31
4     1 2018-02-01 2018-07-13 2007-10-16 2018-12-31
5     1 2018-11-15 2019-02-21 2007-10-16 2018-12-31
```

I would like to calculate days that the 5 small start-end intervals in a `[event_peak = "2007-10-16", event_end = "2018-12-31"]` interval. For illustration, I draw a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS99l.jpg). The goal is to calculate the red line.

The first step is to calculate the number of days(`days_in_ei`) that each `[start_date, end_date]` time interval is overlapping with `[event_peak, event_end]` event time interval.

Something like,

```
df %>% 
  mutate(days_in_ei = case_when(
    end_date < event_peak ~ 0L,
    start_date > event_end ~ 0L,
    end_date >=event_peak & end_date < event_end & start_date < event_peak ~ as.integer(end_date - event_peak),
    end_date >= event_end & start_date < event_peak ~ as.integer(event_end - event_peak),
    start_date >= event_peak & end_date < event_end ~ as.integer(end_date - start_date),
    start_date >= event_peak & start_date < event_end & end_date > event_end ~ as.integer(event_end - start_date),
  ))
df
     id start_date end_date   event_peak event_end  days_in_ei         
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>          <int>     
1     1 2007-04-21 2007-09-23 2007-10-16 2008-12-31          0        
2     1 2007-08-23 2007-10-30 2007-10-16 2008-12-31         14        
3     1 2007-12-01 2008-04-01 2007-10-16 2008-12-31        122 \ overlap
4     1 2008-02-01 2008-07-13 2007-10-16 2008-12-31        163 / overlap
5     1 2008-11-15 2009-02-21 2007-10-16 2008-12-31         46
```

If I sum `days_in_ei`, I get `345 = 0 + 14 + 122 + 163 + 46`. However, Row 3 and Row 4 exist some overlapping days, and I like to count the duplicating day once. The final results is something like this:

```
df
     id days_in_ei         
  <dbl> <int>     
1     1 285
```

where `285 = 0 + 14 + 225 + 46`, and `225 = ymd("2008-07-13") - ymd("2007-12-01")`

Comment: Which red line? There are 3 red lines in your picture.

Comment: What is your expected output for this data? Can you share the calculation for it?